# Javascript/CSS to disable rubber-band end of page scroll for Safari on iPad?

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, safari, scroll

It's that grey area at when you've reached the bottom of the page. I've tried it all!

Viewports, overflow, etc. The methods that do what I need (lock the page in place) **also disable zoom, which I need.** My web app involves people grabbing moveable images and divs. If they touch the background instead and drag, then the whole page drags and snaps - it is irritating, but not the end of the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iScroll does a fantastic job of handling framed scrolling. It may be worth looking at.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Comment: Yeah, it saved me a few times too

Comment: Well, it actually disabled the pinch zoom. But double tap zoom still worked, and I'll live.

Answer (score 2):

you can add a touchmove listener to the body so that it doesn't react like the other elements:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){ event.preventDefault(); },false);
```

Comment: I am not sure how to install this. Do I just put it in <script> tags?